# PHP/Google Sheets: Import CSV from a website with download function

Tags: php, csv, google-sheets, import, download

I have a link where upon visiting with correct credentials in the URL the browser will download a CSV.

Upon visiting the site, a PHP function like this is immediately called:

```
public function getCsv(): void
    {
        if ($this->checkPassword()) {
            // collects CSV content

            \fputcsv(//puts in CSV content);
        }

        echo 'Invalid password. Please try again.';
        exit;
    }

private function checkPassword() {
   //checks password
}
```

I want to call said link from gSheets like this:

```
=IMPORTDATA("http://website.net/csvDownload/password=CORRECT_PASSWORD")
```

If I call the URL in the Browser, it will correctly both collect and download the data as CSV.
However, in gSheets I receive the following error:

```
Could not fetch url: ...
```

Does someone know an answer to this problem?
Do I have to change my PHP function in order for it to work or do I change the call from gSheets?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you could provide a sample csv file in a site with a password (assuming you give out its password), I'll try showing you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORT` functions of google sheet is limited only to unauthenticated/public sites. If you wish to import the data on your sheet with any type of authentication, then you might want to do it via Apps Script's `UrlFetchApp`.

#### Resource:

- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)